# Regular expression problem

Tags: javascript, regex

Expression should start with a alphanumeric and should have alphabets, `@`, `$`, `%`, `_`, `-` and a single space in the middle and should ends with alphanumeric.

E.g.

```
1a1       -- valid
1111      -- invalid
2222$2211 -- valid
%11a25    -- invalid
```

Comment: Gimmeh teh codez?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps we need a `tehcodez.stackexchange.com` site to migrate these kind of questions to :). @Akhilesh singh, you may want to rephrase that so it actually is a question. If you've already tried something yourself, please post that as well: it now looks like you're simply dumping your work here for someone else to do.

Comment: where is the space in your examples?

Comment: @sacklpicka I believe the OP meant the space was part of the character class in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

This will match one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by any alphabetic characters plus the extra characters, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.

```
/^[a-z\d]+[a-z @$%_-][a-z\d]+$/i
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Pe4RU/).

The fiddle validates the same as your test data.

You should learn about [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Javascript still doesn’t have Unicode support, does it?  I mean stuff like `\pL` and `\p{Alphabetic}` and such.

Comment: @tchrist It stores its chars as UTF-16 but I'm pretty sure (at least I've never read about it) it doesn't support Unicode character ranges. `\pL` fails on ASCII range chars so it doesn't appear to. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/HRV9P/).

Comment: @alex I don't quite know what exactly you mean by Unicode character ranges, but there is a lot more to [Unicode support than just general categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Unicode). As that Wikipedia  page mentions, just in properties alone there are things like `\p{Armenian}`, `\p{Script=Armenian}`, `\p{Lu}`, `\p{Lowercase}`,
`\p{White_Space}`, `\p{Alphabetic}`, `\p{Math}`, `\p{Dash}`,
`\p{Bidi_Class=Right_to_Left}`, `\p{Word_Break=A_Letter}`, and
`\p{Numeric_Value=10}`. See [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) for other requirements.

Comment: @tchrist Interesting, thanks for the links. You seem to be the regex expert, so what options do we have in JavaScript for matching `\pL` characters?

Comment: @alex: To the best of my knowledge, there is no solution to matching `\p{Letter}` code points, so you are just point-blank screwed in Javascript when it comes to dealing with Unicode. Considering that UTF-8 has become the dominant web encoding, this is a Major Problem.

Comment: thanx for reply me..the answer u gave me that no working properlyn bcoz if i write like-- "akhilesh@123  singh" its not working... the special character mention above should be come atleast one time,but if it is more than one then it should be work.... kindly give Regular exp. for this...

Comment: @Akhilesh So you can learn something, I'll give you a hint. `+` is a shortcut to `{1,}`, which means *match one or more times*. I'm sure you can adapt my example above to your requirement (which was unclear in your original question).

Comment: i tried this,but getting actual one.i written like this../^[a-z\d]+[a-z @$%_-]+[a-z\d]+$/i... please correct this..

Answer (score 0):

I think what Akhilesh wants is this regexp:

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z@$%_ -]+[a-z0-9]$/i
```

Edit: Hmm, it matches the description, but not the examples Akhilesh gave.
The example "2222$2211" doensn't match his/her description.